# DNN Free Module Resource - Content Rotator and More

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke and am seeking online resources, more specifically free modules to implement into my site. Can anyone direct me to some quality resources? Currently, I'm looking for a content rotator for the rotation of text testimonials. I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

[SnowCovered](http://www.snowcovered.com) is the main place to get modules.  I don't think there's a view to see only free modules, but you can narrow by categories (to try to find your content rotators), then look to see if there are any free ones.

Comment: I have been to this site, thank you. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a free content rotator, but I may give in and purchase one.

Answer (score 0):

We purchased a module at snowcovered (by mexmax-internet.com) and use it and like it. You can dowload there a trial version to examine its features. Another solution -- we embed some javascript into HTML/Text modules for content rotation.

Comment: The module you mention is the one I am thinking about getting. I'm looking for a rotator that does text only too, and this looks to do the trick. So you are happy with this? I appreciate your input.

Comment: First of all, my goal was to provide our content operators with a tool that they cold stay away from any html/js/jquery tricks with the static content they usualy publish. The module has good architecture: it contains a few static html blocks and each block in turn has two subblocks for content and for summary information. Then you can orgainze rotation of the blocks' conetnt and summary areas in many many many different ways automatically or including contrtols for manual sliding and even your own templates. You can also group your static blocks in one big slide and rotate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post about turning the free Anouncements module into a content rotater. 
http://www.ralphwilliams.com/home/entryid/47/turn-dnn-announcements-module-into-a-jquery-slider.aspx

You can also find a number of free modules on Codeplex.
http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?TagName=DotNetNuke&query=%22DotNetNuke%22